# finding values in pandas series - Python3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, series

i have this excruciatingly annoying problem (i'm quite new to python)

```
df=pd.DataFrame[{'col1':['1','2','3','4']}]

col1=df['col1']
```

Why does `col1[1] in col1` return `False`?

Comment: do you want `print (col1 == col1[1])` ?

Comment: because you're trying to compare a pandas series with a scalar value, what exactly are you trying to do here, test if your value exists anywhere in the column or which rows are equal?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For check values use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
#get value where index is 1
print (col1[1])
2 
#more common with loc
print (col1.loc[1])
2

print (col1 == '2')
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: col1, dtype: bool
```

And if need get rows:

```
print (col1[col1 == '2'])
1    2
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

For check multiple values with `or`:

```
print (col1.isin(['2', '4']))
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
Name: col1, dtype: bool 

print (col1[col1.isin(['2', '4'])])
1    2
3    4
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

And something about `in` for testing membership [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#using-the-in-operator):

> Using the Python in operator on a `Series` tests for membership in the index, not membership among the values.
>
> If this behavior is surprising, keep in mind that using in on a Python dictionary tests keys, not values, and Series are dict-like. To test for membership in the values, use the method **isin()**:
>
> For DataFrames, likewise, in applies to the column axis, testing for membership in the list of column names.

```
#1 is in index
print (1 in col1)
True

#5 is not in index
print (5 in col1)
False

#string 2 is not in index
print ('2' in col1)
False

#number 2 is in index
print (2 in col1)
True
```

You try to find string `2` in index values:

```
print (col1[1])
2

print (type(col1[1]))
<class 'str'>

print (col1[1] in col1)
False
```

Comment: thanks for that. Helped me alot with understanding pandas better, but if i needed a boolean function for a single value how would i do that as `isin()` requires a list

Comment: add `[]` like `print (col1.isin(['2']))`

Comment: but if need check only single value, simplier is `print (col1 == '2')`, it is also faster

Comment: but that would still give a list of all rows of  col1 where it would be true or false right? would there be a way of saying: (in pseudo code) ` is '2' in col1` which would return just True (or False if it wasnt)

Comment: Yes, then use `any` or `all` function - `print ((col1 == '2').any())` it check if at least one `True` and if yes, return `True`

Comment: [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.any.html)

Comment: sweeet. Thanks so much!

Comment: You did not answer the question. The question is how to FIND values, not about how to get them by index. So, anybody knows how to get variable index by variable?

Answer (score 4):

I might be missing something, and this is years later, but as I read the question, you are trying to get the `in` keyword to work on your panda series? So probably want to do:

```
col1[1] in col1.values
```

Because as mentioned above, pandas is looking through the index, and you need to specifically ask it to look at the values of the series, not the index.